# Firebase Cloud Messaging not sending notification with first try - iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using Firebase Console to send notifications to the devices, but for some reason I need to send the same notification twice or three times so it can arrive to the device. I don't know where to look or what to do about this bug, because if my code can receive the notification, I guess my code is right.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the application while sending a test notification? Or maybe leaving logs for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes I leave logs when I receive a notification.

Comment: Well, what do you see when seeing a test notification? Do you see the notification being received?

Comment: Sometimes everything works fine. But sometimes I have to send the notification 2-3 times so it can be received from the device.